# Python: How to pre-calculate the slope of a line segment that will be on the graph in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, quantitative-finance, mplfinance

Given two points,

```
two_points = [(Timestamp('2022-11-25 01:15:00', freq='15T'), 0.08124),
              (Timestamp('2022-11-25 02:15:00', freq='15T'), 0.08041)]
```

Use these two points to draw a line on a candlestick graph. For instance,
[candlesticks graph with a line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psV1N.png).

I want to know the slope of this green line before I draw it on the graph.

But the calculation of the slope is related to the length of the y-axis based on price and the width of the each candlestick based on timeframe.

Is there any good way to calculate the slope of the line? Thanks.

Comment: Try this: [Calculate angle and tangent from base and height](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1273849674)

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, the slope is going to be "Price Change" divided by "Time Change".
That said, you need first to decide **what units you want the slope to be in.**

Let's say, for example, that the Price is in dollars.  If so, do you want to know the slope in `dollars per second`?  `dollars per minute`?  `dollars per hour`?   `dollars per day`?

First break up your two points into Price and Time, then calculate the slope as

```
slope = (price2-price1) / (time2-time1)
```

Here is some example code to find the slope in **`dollars per hour`**:

```py
import pandas as pd

two_points = [(pd.Timestamp('2022-11-25 01:15:00'), 0.08124),
              (pd.Timestamp('2022-11-25 02:15:00'), 0.08041)]

point1 = two_points[0]
point2 = two_points[1]

time1  = point1[0]
time2  = point2[0]

price1 = point1[1]
price2 = point2[1]

price_change = price2 - price1

print('price change: %10.6f' % price_change)

time_change = time2 - time1

print('time change : Timedelta('+str(time_change)+')')

print()
print('time change in seconds: %6.1f' % time_change.seconds)

time_change_in_hours = time_change.seconds/(60*60)

print('time change in hours: %10.4f' % time_change_in_hours)

slope = price_change / time_change_in_hours

print()
print('the slope is %10.6f' % slope,'dollars per hour')
```

---

The output from the above code:

```
price change:  -0.000830
time change : Timedelta(0 days 01:00:00)

time change in seconds: 3600.0
time change in hours:     1.0000

the slope is  -0.000830 dollars per hour
```